# What does the word "with" mean in "omitted with no loss of meaning"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> After a verb of attribution (said, stated, announced, disclosed), the word “that” often can be omitted with no loss of meaning.

I have checked the [Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/with)

But I don't think I could found an appropriate definition to explain the word "with" in this sentence.

Comment: With no loss = without any loss.

Comment: You have chosen an answer that contains incorrect information. You should wait at least twenty-four hours for more answers. But since you have chosen an answer, you will less likely get more answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment "***with no*** loss of meaning" is essentially the same as "***without*** loss of meaning".  One can employ such a substitution if that's easier for one to comprehend.

In the phrase "*can be omitted with no loss*" the preposition "with" establishes ***the causal relationship*** between the verb "omitted" and the noun phrase "no loss".  Thus the overall explanation of

> ... the word “that” often can be omitted ***with*** no loss of meaning.

is that the omission (of the word "that") *often **causes** no loss of meaning*, i.e. the meaning often stays the same even if the word "that" is omitted.

Comment: *With* most often indicates a causal relationship when it can be replaced with *because of.* There is no causal relationship implied by 'with' in the sentence at hand.

Comment: Consider providing your own answer before downvoting.  The choice of the "accepted" answer can be made again, I've seen it done.

Comment: BTW, saying something is wrong does not make it wrong, no matter how much you want it. You need to prove it.

Comment: If you want to invent a relationship, you could just as well say *resultative*.

Comment: And the difference is...?

Comment: If you have a question about English, ask it as a proper question. I'm not going to teach you English by means of comments.

Comment: Or, do you really not know the difference between *causes* and *results in*?

Comment: I thought you were going to answer this question instead of continue your exchange with me...